# The mysql join query runned on nodejs gets null results though the given query has no problem

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm now trying to get some data by executing a 'JOIN' query on the server(nodejs), but it keeps giving a nulled result.

Below is the query:

```js
    const selectNameSql=`SELECT 
    data_db.assets.name_assets, data_db.assets.id_assets, 
    data_db.threats.name_threats, data_db.threats.id_threats, 
    data_db.vulns.name_vulns, data_db.vulns.id_vulns 
    FROM 
    data_db.threats 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.assets 
    ON data_db.assets.id_assets=data_db.threats.id_assets 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.vulns 
    ON data_db.vulns.id_assets=data_db.assets.id_assets 
    WHERE 
    data_db.assets.id_assets=? AND data_db.vulns.id_vulns=? AND data_db.threats.id_threats=?`
```

and below is the code where the query executed:

```js
    exports.test=async function(req,res,next){
    const selectNameSql=`SELECT 
    data_db.assets.name_assets, data_db.assets.id_assets, 
    data_db.threats.name_threats, data_db.threats.id_threats, 
    data_db.vulns.name_vulns, data_db.vulns.id_vulns 
    FROM 
    data_db.threats 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.assets 
    ON data_db.assets.id_assets=data_db.threats.id_assets 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.vulns 
    ON data_db.vulns.id_assets=data_db.assets.id_assets 
    WHERE 
    data_db.assets.id_assets=? AND data_db.vulns.id_vulns=? AND data_db.threats.id_threats=?`;
    var a = await db.query(selectNameSql, [2, 3, 4], function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err){ console.log(err);}
        else{console.log('SO SAD');}
    });
    console.log(a);}
```

Though executing the query directly on the database works really well,
execution of the code upper on the nodejs server shows a result like below:

```
<ref *1> Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function (anonymous)],
    packet: [Function (anonymous)],
    timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
    end: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
  _callSite: Error
      at Protocol._enqueue (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
      at Connection.query (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
      at exports.test (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/routes/analysis/analysis.controller.js:334:22)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at /home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
      at Function.process_params (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
      at next (/home/tv/Desktop/CapTeen_repo/CapTeen/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular *1], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT \n' +
    '    data_db.assets.name_assets, data_db.assets.id_assets, \n' +
    '    data_db.threats.name_threats, data_db.threats.id_threats, \n' +
    '    data_db.vulns.name_vulns, data_db.vulns.id_vulns \n' +
    '    FROM \n' +
    '    data_db.threats \n' +
    '    RIGHT JOIN data_db.assets \n' +
    '    ON data_db.assets.id_assets=data_db.threats.id_assets \n' +
    '    RIGHT JOIN data_db.vulns \n' +
    '    ON data_db.vulns.id_assets=data_db.assets.id_assets \n' +
    '    WHERE \n' +
    '    data_db.assets.id_assets=2 AND data_db.vulns.id_vulns=3 AND data_db.threats.id_threats=4',
  values: [ 2, 3, 4 ],
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection: <ref *2> Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    config: ConnectionConfig {
      host: '-----(I erased it)-----',
      port: 3306,
      localAddress: undefined,
      socketPath: undefined,
      user: '----(I erased it)----',
      password: '-----(I erased it)----',
      database: 'data_db',
      connectTimeout: 10000,
      insecureAuth: false,
      supportBigNumbers: false,
      bigNumberStrings: false,
      dateStrings: false,
      debug: undefined,
      trace: true,
      stringifyObjects: false,
      timezone: 'local',
      flags: '',
      queryFormat: undefined,
      pool: undefined,
      ssl: false,
      localInfile: true,
      multipleStatements: false,
      typeCast: true,
      maxPacketSize: 0,
      charsetNumber: 33,
      clientFlags: 455631,
      protocol41: true
    },
    _socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 8,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 150,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: true,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _protocol: Protocol {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readable: true,
      writable: true,
      _config: [ConnectionConfig],
      _connection: [Circular *2],
      _callback: null,
      _fatalError: null,
      _quitSequence: null,
      _handshake: true,
      _handshaked: true,
      _ended: false,
      _destroyed: false,
      _queue: [Array],
      _handshakeInitializationPacket: [HandshakeInitializationPacket],
      _parser: [Parser],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _connectCalled: true,
    state: 'authenticated',
    threadId: 57,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
SO SAD
```

I can't figure out how to solve this problem, so if anyone knows, please tell me how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysql` package does not support `async await`, you can either try to change your code like this and use the callback:

```
exports.test = function (req, res, next) {
  const selectNameSql = `SELECT 
    data_db.assets.name_assets, data_db.assets.id_assets, 
    data_db.threats.name_threats, data_db.threats.id_threats, 
    data_db.vulns.name_vulns, data_db.vulns.id_vulns 
    FROM 
    data_db.threats 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.assets 
    ON data_db.assets.id_assets=data_db.threats.id_assets 
    RIGHT JOIN data_db.vulns 
    ON data_db.vulns.id_assets=data_db.assets.id_assets 
    WHERE 
    data_db.assets.id_assets=? AND data_db.vulns.id_vulns=? AND data_db.threats.id_threats=?`;

  db.query(
    selectNameSql,
    [2, 3, 4],
    function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rows);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Or use the `mysql2` package with `async await`:

```
exports.test = async function (req, res, next) {
    const selectNameSql = `SELECT 
        data_db.assets.name_assets, data_db.assets.id_assets, 
        data_db.threats.name_threats, data_db.threats.id_threats, 
        data_db.vulns.name_vulns, data_db.vulns.id_vulns 
        FROM 
        data_db.threats 
        RIGHT JOIN data_db.assets 
        ON data_db.assets.id_assets=data_db.threats.id_assets 
        RIGHT JOIN data_db.vulns 
        ON data_db.vulns.id_assets=data_db.assets.id_assets 
        WHERE 
        data_db.assets.id_assets=? AND data_db.vulns.id_vulns=? AND data_db.threats.id_threats=?`;
  
    try {
      const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
      const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: '<your-host>',
        user: '<your-user>',
        database: '<your-database>',
      });
  
      const a = await connection.execute(selectNameSql, [2, 3, 4]);
      console.log(a);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

For more on mysql2 check out their official [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)

Comment: OMGOMGOMGOMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you soooooooo much!!!! It works!!!!!! I didn't know that mysql doesn't support async/await, so it might have taken more than a week for me to troubleshoot it if you haven't told me about mysql2!!!!!!!! You LITERALLY saved my project! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is possibly caused by mixing callbacks with promises (the "SO SAD" message is being logged from inside the callback, but you're not doing anything with the results there).

Either stick with a promise-based solution *or* a callback-based solution, but not both (although I can't find anything in the `mysql` package documentation that suggests it actually supports promises?).

Comment: Callbacks mixed with promises? You mean 'await' db.query(~~~, ~~, 'function(~~)') is the problem, right? Then if you don't mind, would you tell me the method to solve it? I know that you already told me to stick with a promise-based solution or a callback-based solution but because I'm a total newbie in the programming field, it is hard for me to figure out what to do. Anyway, I know what is the promise and callback....!

Comment: Can you tell me which MySQL package you're using?

Comment: I was using mysql1 at that period, but after I saw the answer above I change the package to mysql2 and it has been working well. By the way, I really appreciate your concern and help!